# Positioning Windows on multiple displays

Tags: windows, winapi

If I have 2 monitors that sit side by side and I want to position a window in the upper left of the 2nd monitor, would the correct coordinates be `[SCREEN1_WIDTH, 0]`? The 2nd monitor sits to the right of the other monitor.

```
SetWindowPos(myHwnd, 0, SCREEN1_WIDTH, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
```

I dont have a second monitor to test this. Then would `GetWindowRect(myHwnd, &r)` return the same coordinates (absolute coords) or would it be relative to the 2nd monitor?

Comment: Monitor 2 could be to the left of monitor 1. if thats the case, then the coordinates are negative. The monitor could also be positioned above, in which case the position at screen 1's width could be off the edge of the primary display. Your best bet would be to use `EnumDisplayMonitors` to get the rectangle for the windows, and use those rectangles to position your window. Once you do move it, `GetWindowRect` does indeed give you the correct screen coordinates.

Comment: Monitors always touch at some point with another one, but they don't have to touch in their top-left/top-right corners. You need to enumerate them to find out their coordinates.

Comment: Since you never specified, **how** you want to position windows across multiple displays, any answer is equally right and wrong. That makes this question fairly useless.